# How to execute 2 or more SQL queries in PHP without joining tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, multi-query

To select data from 1 table I'm using following code:

```
if(isset($UserID)) {    

    $users = $con->prepare("
    SELECT DISTINCT
         d.FirstName                
        ,d.LastName                 
        ,d.Picture  
    FROM Details d 
    WHERE d.UserId = ?
    ");

    $users->bind_param('i', $GetUserId);
    $users->execute();

    $users->bind_result(        
        $FirstName,             
        $LastName,          
        $Picture
    );


} else {
    echo "There is no User ID detected, try to refresh browser.";   
}

while ($users->fetch()) { ?>

    <div class="grid-group">
    <span>Personal Details</span>
        <div class="grid-column">
            <div class="grid-item header">First Name </div>             
            <div class="grid-item header">Last Name </div> 
            <div class="grid-item header">Picture </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="grid-column">
            <div class="grid-item"><?php echo $FirstName; ?></div>          
            <div class="grid-item"><?php echo $LastName; ?></div>
            <div class="grid-item"><?php echo $Picture; ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

How can I add 1 more query to select some data from another table? Something like:

```
SELECT Foo, Bar, FooBar
FROM Bizz
WHERE UserId = ?
```

Should I use `mysqli_multi_query`? But how can I use It and `bind_result` after It? I can't achieve correct syntax. Or there is any other way?

I will need to print data from 2 tables like this:

```
while ($users->fetch()) { ?>

    <div class="grid-group">
    <span>Personal Details</span>
        <div class="grid-column">
            <div class="grid-item header">First Name </div>             
            <div class="grid-item header">Last Name </div> 
            <div class="grid-item header">Picture </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="grid-column">
            <div class="grid-item"><?php echo $FirstName; ?></div>          
            <div class="grid-item"><?php echo $LastName; ?></div>
            <div class="grid-item"><?php echo $Picture; ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-group">
    <span>Foo Bar</span>
        <div class="grid-column">
            <div class="grid-item header">Foo </div>            
            <div class="grid-item header">Bar </div> 
            <div class="grid-item header">FooBar </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="grid-column">
            <div class="grid-item"><?php echo $Foo; ?></div>            
            <div class="grid-item"><?php echo $Bar; ?></div>
            <div class="grid-item"><?php echo $FooBar; ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

For some reasons I can't use `JOINS`. Have you any ideas?

**UPDATE**

If I prepare 2 queries in following, I got blank screen:

```
if(isset($UserID)) {    

    $users = $con->prepare("
    SELECT DISTINCT
         d.FirstName                
        ,d.LastName                 
        ,d.Picture  
    FROM Details  
    WHERE d.UserId = ?
    ");

    $users->bind_param('i', $GetUserId);
    $users->execute();

    $users->bind_result(        
        $FirstName,             
        $LastName,          
        $Picture
    );

    $users2 = $con->prepare("
    SELECT DISTINCT
          Foo               
        , Bar               
        , FooBar 
    FROM Bizz  
    WHERE UserId = ?
    ");

    $users2->bind_param('i', $GetUserId);
    $users2->execute();

    $users2->bind_result(       
        $Foo,           
        $Bar,           
        $FooBar
    );

} else {
    echo "There is no User ID detected, try to refresh browser.";   
}
while ($users->fetch()) { ?>
...
```

Have you any ideas?

Comment: Is there a link between those 2 tables ? Or can you simply do 2 seperate queries... ?

Comment: you can simply just prepare and execute a new query? i don't see why you couldn't?

Comment: @Random I want simple use separate queries.

Comment: then do so? what is stopping you? just simply copy and paste from your prepare to the bind result and change the query?

Comment: So why don't you simply make 2 separate queries, storing the result in 2 seperate arrays ?

Comment: @Random If I'm trying to prepare 2 queries I got blank screen.

Comment: @Jester updated my question with sample data how I'm trying to prepare 2 queries, but I can't get successful. I got blank screen.

Comment: if you have a blank screen that means there are errors, you need to turn on error_reporting

Comment: @YourCommonSense you marked It as duplicate, but It not solved my problem.

Comment: Just follow instructions from there and fix the error.

Comment: @Infinity What if you `$users->store_result();` `$users->bind_result($param);` `$users->close();` then free it if it has to be a big data after fetching

Answer (score 0):

to know why you get a blank screen you have to turn on error_reporting, add the following at the start of your php code before anything else:

```
error_reporting(-1);
```

Also add some code to show errors that might happen in MySQL:

```
if(isset($UserID)) {    

$users = $con->prepare("
SELECT DISTINCT
     d.FirstName                
    ,d.LastName                 
    ,d.Picture  
FROM Details  
WHERE d.UserId = ?
");
if (!$users) {
    echo 'MySQL Connect Error in Query: (' . $mysqli->errno . ') ';
}

$binding = $users->bind_param('i', $GetUserId);
if (!$binding) {
    echo 'MySQL Connect Error in Query: (' . $mysqli->errno . ') ';
}

if($users->execute() == false) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $con->error;
}

$binding_results = $users->bind_result(        
    $FirstName,             
    $LastName,          
    $Picture
);
if (!$binding_results) {
    echo 'MySQL Connect Error in Query: (' . $mysqli->errno . ') ';
}

$users2 = $con->prepare("
SELECT DISTINCT
      Foo               
    , Bar               
    , FooBar 
FROM Bizz  
WHERE UserId = ?
");
if (!$users2) {
    echo 'MySQL Connect Error in Query: (' . $mysqli->errno . ') ';
}

$binding2 = $users2->bind_param('i', $GetUserId);
if (!$binding2) {
    echo 'MySQL Connect Error in Query: (' . $mysqli->errno . ') ';
}

if($users2->execute() == false) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $con->error;
}

$binding_results2 = $users2->bind_result(       
    $Foo,           
    $Bar,           
    $FooBar
);
if (!$binding_results2) {
    echo 'MySQL Connect Error in Query: (' . $mysqli->errno . ') ';
}
```

I can see one mistake in your first query. you are using d.FirstName where as the table name is Details

Comment: Still blank screen, that's not about alias `d`, I just missed It when wrote sample data. And also `error_reporting` was on before. `if($users->execute() == false) {` not helped too.

Comment: That's why I've asked this question, looks like can't simple use 2 queries.

Comment: you should add catch mysql errors after preparing, binding and executing then. also is there any php code before this that you left out?

Comment: I edited my answer, i think that should catch any errors in the mysql

Comment: There is something wrong. I've tested both queries 1st and 2nd in phpmyadmin, both selecting results correctly. After trying to catch errors in your provided way I got message: `MySQL Connect Error in Query: ()` 2 times without errno. I've tested It appears in `if (!$binding_results)` and `$users2 = $con->prepare("`, but It looks like that there is no *MySQL* mistakes, quesries working correctly...